# cross compile linux kernel for beaglebone black

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I try to crosscompile the linux kernel 3.14 much time for my beaglebone black with different ARCH(x64, i386) and different toolchain. But none of them can start correctly. It always stop at

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80007fc0 ...
Image Name:   Linux-3.17.1+
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    6732680 Bytes = 6.4 MiB
Load Address: 80008000
Entry Point:  80008000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000
XIP Kernel Image ... OK
OK
Using Device Tree in place at 80f80000, end 80f92df6

Starting kernel ...
```

I think I use a incorrect toolchain, So I try to use the toolchain in  ti StarsWares and linaro-toolchain. But it still not work.  I also think I need to use 32bit ubuntu instead of my ubuntu 14.10(64bit), but it still not work.

finally, I try to compile an sample c program and try to run it on my beaglebone. it says:

```
root@beaglebone:~\# ./test 
-sh: ./test: No such file or directory
```

it seems I use incorrect toolchain.

I try to use the the kernel config file on:

```
git://github.com/beagleboard/kernel.git
```

but it still stop at:

```
Starting kernel ...
```

---

**My crosscompile  tool chain was.**

[linaro toolchain](http://releases.linaro.org/14.09/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux.tar.xz)

**My kernel build command was:**

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/larry/develop/linaro-toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

`make modules ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/larry/develop/linaro-toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

`make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=mymodules ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/larry/develop/linaro-toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

`make LOADADDR=0x80008000 uImage dtbs ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/larry/develop/linaro-toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

**kernel .config was here:**

[kernel .config](http://www.larrylife.com/beaglebone.config)

**My U-Boot config was:**

```
`U-Boot# printenv
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=am335x
board_name=A335BNLT
board_rev=000B
bootcmd=gpio set 53; i2c mw 0x24 1 0x3e; run findfdt; mmc dev 0; if mmc rescan ; then echo micro SD card found;setenv mmcdev 0;else echo No micro SD card found, setting mmcdev to 1;setenv mmcdev 1;fi;setenv bootpart ${mmcdev}:2;mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then gpio set 54; echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded environment from ${bootenv};run importbootenv;fi;if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...;run uenvcmd;fi;gpio set 55; if run loaduimage; then gpio set 56; run loadfdt;run mmcboot;fi;fi;
bootdelay=1
bootdir=/boot
bootenv=uEnv.txt
bootfile=uImage
bootpart=0:2
console=ttyO0,115200n8
cpu=armv7
dfu_alt_info_emmc=rawemmc mmc 0 3751936
dfu_alt_info_mmc=boot part 0 1;rootfs part 0 2;MLO fat 0 1;MLO.raw mmc 100 100;u-boot.img.raw mmc 300 3C0;u-boot.img fat 0 1;uEnv.txt fat 0 1
dfu_alt_info_nand=SPL part 0 1;SPL.backup1 part 0 2;SPL.backup2 part 0 3;SPL.backup3 part 0 4;u-boot part 0 5;kernel part 0 7;rootfs part 0 8
ethact=cpsw
ethaddr=1c:ba:8c:95:c8:fa
fdt_high=0xffffffff
fdtaddr=0x80F80000
fdtfile=am335x-boneblack.dtb
findfdt=if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evm.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335X_SK; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evmsk.dtb; fi;if test $board_name = A335BONE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bone.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335BNLT; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack.dtb; fi
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc ...; env import -t $loadaddr $filesize
kloadaddr=0x80007fc0
loadaddr=0x80200000
loadbootenv=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenv}
loadfdt=load mmc ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}
loadramdisk=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${rdaddr} ramdisk.gz
loaduimage=load mmc ${bootpart} ${kloadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${mmcroot} 
rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}
mmcboot=echo Booting from mmc ...; run mmcargs; bootm ${kloadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
mmcdev=0
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait
mtdids=nand0=omap2-nand.0
mtdparts=mtdparts=omap2-nand.0:128k(SPL),128k(SPL.backup1),128k(SPL.backup2),128k(SPL.backup3),1920k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-env),5m(kernel),-(rootfs)
nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${nandroot} 
rootfstype=${nandrootfstype}
nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; run nandargs; nand read ${loadaddr} ${nandsrcaddr} ${nandimgsize}; bootm ${loadaddr}
nandimgsize=0x500000
nandroot=ubi0:rootfs rw ubi.mtd=7,2048
nandrootfstype=ubifs rootwait=1
nandsrcaddr=0x280000
netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=/dev/nfs 
nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath},${nfsopts} rw ip=dhcp
netboot=echo Booting from network ...; setenv autoload no; dhcp; tftp ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}; tftp ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}; run netargs; bootm ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
nfsopts=nolock
ramargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${ramroot} 
rootfstype=${ramrootfstype}
ramboot=echo Booting from ramdisk ...; run ramargs; bootm ${loadaddr} ${rdaddr} ${fdtaddr}
ramroot=/dev/ram0 rw ramdisk_size=65536 initrd=${rdaddr},64M
ramrootfstype=ext2
rdaddr=0x81000000
rootpath=/export/rootfs
soc=am33xx
spiargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${spiroot} 
rootfstype=${spirootfstype}
spiboot=echo Booting from spi ...; run spiargs; sf probe ${spibusno}:0; sf read ${loadaddr} ${spisrcaddr} ${spiimgsize}; bootm ${loadaddr}
spibusno=0
spiimgsize=0x362000
spiroot=/dev/mtdblock4 rw
spirootfstype=jffs2
spisrcaddr=0xe0000
static_ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
usbnet_devaddr=1c:ba:8c:95:c8:fa
vendor=ti
ver=U-Boot 2013.04-dirty (Jun 19 2013 - 09:57:14)

Environment size: 3877/131068 bytes
```

It spend my to much time. Anyone Can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess that installing Linux on your desktop could help: first, you'll learn Linux, and secondly, cross-compilation is probably easier on Linux.

Comment: You may not have a cross compile issue.  Booting from `0x80007fc0` seem typical for Beaglebone, but not other ARM boards.  Try loading the uImage to `0x80200000` and the DTB to `0x81200000` as described  [here](http://elinux.org/Building_BBB_Kernel).  These addresses have to be modified in the **bootcmd** U-Boot environment variable.

Comment: *"I try to compile an sample c program and try to run it on my beaglebone..."* -- This failure is very likely a shared library issue.  Link your program statically using the `-static` GCC compile/link option.

Comment: I loading uImage to 0x80200000 and the DTB `0x81200000` in the uboot, but it still stop at `Starting kernel`,  I use the uboot default config, it can boot the `kernel-3.8`(system default), but can't boot from my `kernel-3.17`(compile by me). @sawdust

Comment: Then you need to start explaining what your build environment is, what toolchain you are using, the commands you use to build the kernel, and the U-Boot environment variables.  Add this information to your question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26461430/edit).

Comment: I had update more info about this question, thanks @sawdust

Comment: (Q1) What **defconfig** file did you use before you started compiling the kernel?  That should have been the first `make` command. (Q2) What tutorial, if any, are you using? Try following [this tutorial](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php/BeagleBoneBlack_Building_Kernel) (Q3) Why does the kernel *.config* file indicate version "3.14.0", but the boot output indicates "3.17.1+"? (Q4) Are you booting from NAND or SDcard or ???  Including the output before the *"## Booting kernel from Legacy Image..."* would make this obvious to us.

Comment: I am sorry I too late to response you (1): I not use any defconfig file. (2)

Comment: I am sorry I too late to response you:                             (1): I not use any defconfig file.                                 (2): I first use 3.17+, but it not work, I try to use 3.14.0 with the .config from the beaglebone git. but it still stop at Start kernel.                                                         (3): I used to read the lots of tutorial on the Internet. include this one.                                                       (4): This problem always occur on boot the NAND or SDcard@sawdust

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problems with Beagleboard xM. We followed the steps on wiki pages but it always used to hung up at Starting kernel....

And one of the freakiest solutions was to use the HDMI cable to plug it in to the monitor instead of using minicom or other serial console. Earlier we didn't have a monitor supporting HDMI...but when we changed the monitor and plugged in with HDMI...there it was the sought after Angstrom sign and log in screen.

I searched a lot for the reason why this happened. No reply's yet but maybe you can change the console parameter in the bootargs. we were using the standard ttyS0 change it to ttyO2 and try or just try plugging in the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble on my debian pre-installed BBB. I compiled the 3.14 kernel and when I tried it on my BBB it used to get stuck at "Starting kernel..."

But my mistake was that I had only replaced the `zImage` in `/boot/uboot/` with the new one. When I replaced the `am335x-boneblack.dtb` in `/boot/uboot/dtbs/` with the one I compiled in 3.14 it started working. The new `am335x-boneblack.dtb` can be found in `kernel_dir/arch/arm/boot/dts`. And don't forget  to copy the directory with the new modules (from `modules_install` command) to `/lib/modules` of the BBB

Answer (score 0):

`root@beaglebone:~\# ./test 
-sh: ./test: No such file or directory`

This issue is due to `shared library issue`which is not same as the one having rootfs and your toolchain.

How you can verify..?

`compile the code with statically linked`

e.g arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -static -o hello

and try to execute.

Also check this [Linux Cant find dynamically linked applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898649/linux-cant-find-dynamically-linked-applications/18942117#18942117)

Comment: yeah, You are right, thank you. it can execute now. But I my custom kernel still stop at                                          `Starting kernel ...`, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem and finally solved it by put dtb at 0x88000000.
I guess the original position may overlap the kernel....