# Beaglebone cross compilation

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am a freshman for the beaglebone. I need your help. I have installed the cross compiler toolchain arm-linux-gnueabi on my 64 bit xubuntu in eclipse as well as codeblocks environment. I have made a hello world program, cross compiled it in 3 ways using eclipse , using terminal,using Codeblocks. But when i run my executable file in Beaglebone i get the error saying cant load shared file libstdc++6.so.6:file not found.

Though i have already installed latest libstdc++6,ia32-libs and configured it. I am using ssh for logging into my Beaglebone. My all projects are pending because of this. Please suggest solution. I will be grateful to you. I have worked according to derek molloy c,c++ video but still got the error. I think it is because of difference between 32 bit and 64 bit in beaglebone and laptop respectively.

Comment: have a look @ this it might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898649/linux-cant-find-dynamically-linked-applications/18942117#18942117  ,copy your toolchain having `libstdc++6.so.6` to your target rootfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought abi used was arm-linux-gnueabi but when i got the details of abi version running on my beagleboard i found it was arm-linux-gnueabihf. So i just replaced the compiler and then it was able to find all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really installed libstdc++6,ia32-libs on your BB? It looks like x86 lib. Take a look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It already provides BB target, so you can get your basic rootfs quite quickly. Then just add needed packages and you are done. The main benefit, when using such distro like BR, that you have all needed dependencies in your rootfs, that you burn on your microSD card. BR also provides [Eclipse plugin](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_integration_with_eclipse).